# :not() Selector in a multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a multiple select and I need just to access the items which are not selected

I tried the following code but it does not work because it returns also the selected items. Any hints how to fix this code?

```
$('select.myMultippleSelect option:not(selected)');

[
<option value=​"13">​Normal User​</option>​
, 
<option value=​"14" selected=​"selected">​Euna Baumbach​</option>​
, 
<option value=​"15">​Test​</option>​
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out its working for me , you forgot to include : before selected in you code , updated code is

```
$('select.myMultippleSelect option:not(:selected)');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uzhWS/26/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo, should be a `:` before `selected`. Does that exist in your code? If it does, there's your problem.

Comment: Confirmed that $('select.myMultippleSelect option:not(:selected)'); is working.